# VHDL: Concat inout std_logic into std_logic_vector signal

Tags: vhdl

I have several tri-stateable (inout) std_logic port pins defined in my top-level port declaration. I have a dedicated internal component that is needing to utilize these, but its port is defined as having an inout std_logic_vector (not my code and I can't change), which I need to concatenate my std_logic into a std_logic_vector to make it happy.

The problem is: I'm not sure how to do this.

I thought that ALIAS would be the correct route, but apparently the concatenation operator can't be used when defining an alias.

Then I thought I'd just use a std_logic_vector internal signal:

```
mySignal <= inOutBit2 & inOutBit1 & inOutBit0; --Input route

componentPort => mySignal, --Component use

inOutBit2 <= mySignal(2);
inOutBit1 <= mySignal(1);
inOutBit0 <= mySignal(0); --Output route
```

but this would not synthesize as it viewed inOutBitn as having multiple drivers.

Is there anything I can do to get this to synthesize? I know I can just declare my top-level inout port to be a std_logic_vector, but that is sub-optimal as we have a a well defined port-labeling convention.

Comment: Can't you use `mySignal(0) <= inOutBit0` etc. instead of the first line?

Comment: For a standard VHDL signal, there is no difference between assigning each bit of a vector or using concatenation to assign the entire vector in 1 line. Or are you saying that there is a difference when it comes to inout ports?

Comment: My mistake; you're right. Can you add some more code (the definitions) and the synthesis error / wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I understand that both the top-level ports and the component ports are mode `inout`.

If this is so, then it may help if you connect the component ports directly to the external `inout` ports at `std_logic` level, like:

```
componentPort(0) => inOutBit0,  --Component use
componentPort(1) => inOutBit1,  --Component use
componentPort(2) => inOutBit2,  --Component use
```

The intermediate `mySignal` is then not required.

However, the description says that synthesis reports multiple drivers for `inOutBitn`, but I would expect that it reported multiple drivers for `mySignal` in the original code.

Comment: Cool thanks! It completely slipped my mind that you could instantiate components in this way.